# How to align vertical text in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create a vertical line of text to appear next to a box in bootstrap. The placement is off when the screen is fully expanded, and as the screen scales smaller, the words begin to stack as though the entire column they are in was turned sideways. Is there any way to make it so that the text stays in one line, and to align it properly? Here is the html:

```
<div id="pg03" class="container-fluid">     
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="whatis" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <h3 class="vertical"> What is Omni X?</h3>
          </div>
          <div id="infobox" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
            <div class="row">
              <div id="info" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">                  
                <p>Donec id elit non mi </p>
              </div>
              <div id="img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <a href="birdgirl.jpg">
                <img src="birdgirl.jpg" class="center-block">
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="info" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">                  
                <p>Donec id elit non mi </p>
              </div>
              <div id="img" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <a href="birdgirl.jpg">
                <img src="birdgirl.jpg" class="center-block">
                </a>
              </div>       
            </div>  
          </div>    
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.vertical{
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform-origin: right bottom 0;
 font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
 color: #231B65;
 text-align: center;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: white;
 border-width: 4px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: how do you want to align it , there's a vertical-align property with values of : top,bottom,middle,super etc etc..

Comment: I'm not trying to vertically align the text, I am trying to fix the alignment of vertical text, lol. I see how this may appear confusing.